# Modifying ListView scrolling behaviour for fullscreen view of rows

Tags: android, listview, scroll, fullscreen

To display medical scanner images of patients, I use a listview whose rows represent axial slices of the scanner and are displayed fullscreen.

I does work quite well so far.

However, like in most medical imaging software, I would like the scrolling function to behave differently:

- Currently, slices scroll continuously upwards, as showed on the associated image. Two cropped rows are therefore displayed together, while scrolling, until row 2 takes the whole screen and row 1 entirely disappears.[image]
- I would like row 1 to disappear immediately and row 2 (and subsequent rows) to appear immediately when a scroll motion is performed, so that the user does not get the impression that rows are moving upwards.
  [image]

After consulting the android doc, I am not sure that such behaviour is possible with listview.
Any tip would be appreciated !

Comment: use Vertical ViewPager instead of listview

Comment: I thought about it, but I see at least two cons:
- scrolling more than 1 item is mandatory because there are 200 slices at least. 
- Fast scrolling is necessay, which means that some kind of item recycling seems required, as items are quite complex. ListView with ViewHolder pattern seemed appropriate to me